# Algorithm to count identical multisets of characters

Tags: string, algorithm, hash

I am looking for a fast (actual time, not asymptotic complexity) algorithm to count identical multisets of characters. For example, the input

```
BCDEFGH
ABACD
BDCEF
BDCAA
DBACA
DABACA
DABAC
BCDEHFG
```

Has a 4 identical sets, namely

```
ABACD
BDCAA
DBACA
DABAC
```

and another 2 identical sets

```
BCDEFGH
BCDEHFG
```

The sets can be large (>10,000 char)

I am thinking of using a hash then mapping that to a counter, however I have to consider how I can hash efficiently without sorting such that the reordered characters will map to the same hash. One way I imagine to do this to count the number of times each character occurs in an array of integers, then hash that.

Alternatively, are there other algorithms that may perform better in practice? Please also let me know of any speedup tips and tricks

Comment: what is output format you want?

Comment: I want a list (in any format) of the counts of identical sets, eg in the example it would be {4,2}, in any order

Answer (score 0):

For reduced alphabet, as you demonstrate in your example, you can use array of `short[8]`, and count in that array all presence of chars in set. Thereafter, hash that array. See following example:

```
uint16_t arr[8];

bzero(arr, siezeof(arr)); // clear array before usage

for(int i = 0; i < setline.size(); i++) // fill swap-independent arr, O(N)
    arr[setline[i] - 'A']++;

// Hash the array
uint32_t h = 0xDEADBEEF;
for(int i = 0; i < 8; i++)
    h = ((h << 11) | (h >> (32 - 11))) + arr[i];
```